# Intellij Plugin: Cannot init component state exception

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to create an Intellij Idea Plugin with some configurations in `Settings->Tools`.

I have an `ApplicationService` to hold and save those configurations, but an exception occurs when calling `ServiceManager.getService(MyService.class)`, and the configuration don't persist upon reopening Intellij Idea.

Here is the stack trace for the exception:

```
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot init  component state [Plugin: org.mycompany.mycompany-plugin]
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:116)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.initComponent(ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.kt:50)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.initializeComponent$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:358)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:58)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:41)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:115)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:69)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doGetService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:411)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:394)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:20)
    at com.mycompany.config.SettingsService.getInstance(SettingsService.java:14)
    at com.mycompany.config.SettingsConfigurable.reset(SettingsConfigurable.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper.reset(ConfigurableWrapper.java:177)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.reset(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.lambda$createConfigurableComponent$4(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    (a lot more lines here)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: configurationSchemaKey must be specified for com.mycompany.config.SettingsService
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:369)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:100)
    ... 113 more
```

I found no documentation about that "configurationSchemaKey", except for the fact that it's an ApplicationService XML paramter - but I could not find out what value I should put in it. I.

Here's how I defined the service:

```
<applicationService
                serviceImplementation="com.testmycode.config.SettingsService"
                id="com.testmycode.config.SettingsService"/>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configurationSchemaKey` property is a part of the [`ServiceDescriptor`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/components/ServiceDescriptor.java#L41) and is described as:

> Cannot be specified as part of {@link State} because to get annotation, class must be loaded, but it cannot be done for performance reasons.

However, it's not common to create such a service for handling settings.

Please review your current implementation and follow the [Introduction to Settings](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/settings.html) guide in the IntelliJ Platform SDK DevGuide.

Comment: What do you mean it is not common, what else is used to store application state? The [tutorial](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/settings-tutorial.html) you mentioned also describes a service. It also doesn't say anything about setting `configurationSchemaKey`.